# Как заменить символы Python Console в PyCharm с In [2]: на >>>

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня такой вопрос: Как заменить символы Python Console в PyCharm с In [2]: на >>>? И ещё не знаю почему, когда открываю Python Console сразу все верхние надписи закрывают In [1]: и когда что-либо заносишь в In [2]: и нажимаешь исполнение, выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: In [1]: - так выглядит "приглашение" ipython. Глобально поменять приглашение ipython можно как тут описано: https://stummjr.org/post/customize-ipython5-prompt/. "И ещё не знаю почему, когда открываю Python Console сразу все верхние надписи закрывают In [1]: и когда что-либо заносишь в In [2]: и нажимаешь исполнение, выдаёт ошибку." - нужен как минимум скриншот, потому что вообще не понятно, что там у вас происходит. Но лучше отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Можно еще попробовать пакет ipython удалить, но это крайняя мера, по идее без него даже jupyter notebook может перестать работать.

Comment: Вот пробую вставить скриншот: Не получается, в ответе нет этой опции

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, затем для картинки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как красная стрелка показывает, удалось!

(Разумеется, после клика на **OK** и затем запуска Python Console...)

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!

Comment: @Vlad63, не стоит. !-) [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)